# Periodically Updating Backbone JS Model

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using backbone js with an xml api data feed. I have a top-level model for each page that receives the xml and converts it into json. I then have additional methods in the model that return specific parts of the json model to the specific views through a controller. This is all working as expected.

I would like to periodically (via setTimeout) update the top-level model and have it fire the change event and update the views. My question is where I should handle/initialize the firing of this periodic event to update the model since it's not really a user trigger event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give my model a `startUpdate()` method, an `endUpdate()` method, and an internal `onTimerUpdate()` method that did a fetch.  You can then call, on the model, the `startUpdate()` and let it run as needed, pausing it when it would be inconvenient for a server-side update to run (say, in the middle of a customer manipulation of the data), and restarting it after a client-side change had successfully completed a write to the server.

Better yet, you could make it a mixin and use it with a number of different models.

Comment: So I've added startUpdate, endUpdate and onTimerUpdate to my model. I call startUpdate in the index action of my pages controller and pass the model to the various views, which successifully binds the model to the all the views. The problem I'm having now is that I'd like to pass certain parts of the model to different views through the controller (e.g data: model.getDerivedSubModel() ) as a generic attribute to reuse the views.

Comment: But when I try to do this the model is updated, but the derived data returned by the method remains unchanged when the view is re-rendered (like the model doesn't pass through the controller when a view is re-rendered). Is there a way in backbone to bind specific parts of model to a view through a controller? I realize having all this data in one model isn't an ideal case, but I'm not sure how split it up since it originates from one url and is returned in one xml blob.

Comment: Is the model a collection of things?  Or is it just one huge blob?  If it's a collection, you could write dynamic filters and have views only show part of the collection.  It sounds to me, though, like you should instrument (i.e lots of `console.log()s`) your model and see what changes on update, because the view should reflect the current state of the model.  If it changed, so should the view.